# Let $\delta$ be a straight-line segment joining points $1 − i$ and $1$. Evaluate $\int _\delta \bar{z} dz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification

I chose the parameterisation of straight-line segment joining points $1 − i$ and $1$ to be $\delta(t) = (1-i) +ti$  where $t\in [0,1] $

so using definition of path integrals:
$\int _\delta \bar{z} dz$ = $\int_0^1 \overline{(1-i)+ti}  . i dt = \int_0^1 i-1+t\ dt = i-\frac{1}{2}$

is my solution correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for the feedback!